# Angular2 and Highcharts map - map bubbles not showing up

Tags: angular, dictionary, highcharts

I'm trying to use 'mapbubble' series with Highcharts map on Angular2. So far, the map works fine but can't get the bubbles to show up: so there is no error at all, just bubbles not showing up. Here's how I'm using it:

Inside my view component I have declared a `chartOptions` variable which will be used by the `<chart>` tag:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'map-chart-component',
    template: `<chart type="Map" *ngIf="chartOptions" [options]="chartOptions"></chart>`,
    styles: [``]
})

export class MapChartComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    ngOnInit(){
        this.chartOptions = {
            chart: { type: 'map' },
            plotOptions: { map: { allAreas: true } },
            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: { verticalAlign: 'bottom' },
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Countries',
                color: '#E0E0E0',
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                mapData: HighmapsLibrary.customworld,
            }, {
                type: 'mapbubble',
                name: 'Population 2016',
                joinBy: ['iso-a3', 'code3'],
                data: [
                    { code3: "AFG", z: 35530 },
                    { code3: "AGO", z: 29784 },
                    { code3: "ALB", z: 2879 },
                ],
                minSize: 20,
                maxSize: '100%',
            }]
        };

    }
```

On the app-modules.ts:

```
export function highchartsFactory() {
    const hc = require('highcharts');
    const hcmap = require('highcharts/modules/map');
    const hcmore = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
    hcmap(hc);
    hcmore(hc);
    return hc;
}

//and inside providers
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers:[
        {
            provide: HighchartsStatic,
            useFactory: highchartsFactory
        }
    ],
    ...
})
```

I hope the question is full and clear enough! Been searching and trying to figure it out for hours with no success... but I hope it's something simple I'm missing!!

Comment: Is `chartOptions` also in `app.ts` ? It is not that clear in your question.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited the question! `chartOptions` is a variable inside a view component which contains chart options and will be used by the `<chart>` tag (see the HTML part)!

Comment: Could you please reproduce your issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)? It would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your effort! @Kamil's suggestion worked fine in non-Angular environment but still didn't show bubbles inside Angular2.

For anyone having the same problem, it turned out that I had to do a `chart.redraw()` for it to work properly. I'm still figuring out why but it solved my issue for now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your mapbubble series doesn't know which `mapData` to use.

Both of your series use the same map layout so it can be defined in `chart.map` property instead of `mapData` in "Countries" series:

```
{
  chart: {
    map: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Countries',
    color: 'red',
    //mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'] <- MOVED TO chart.map
  }, {
    type: 'mapbubble',
    name: 'Population 2016',
    joinBy: ['name', 'code3'],
    data: [{
        code3: "Nigeria",
        z: 35
      },
      {
        code3: "Poland",
        z: 29
      },
      {
        code3: "Russia",
        z: 28
      },
    ],
    minSize: 20,
    maxSize: '10%',
  }]
}
```

Another way of doing the same thing would be to add this line:

```
 mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world']
```

in **mapbubble** series options.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xapn1srf/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.map

Comment: For some reason, inside Angular2, bubbles weren't still showing up. I get to solve my situation using `chart.redraw()` for now. Thank you for your time!